# bash - parse a http query string

Tags: bash, http, parsing

I have to to parse a query string in `bash`; I found many solutions online, but I've a big problem when the the **asterisk** is a "value" o "key".

**1** - Example that works

```
$ PARAMS="key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4"
$ ARRAY=(${PARAMS//[=&]/ })
$ echo ${ARRAY[@]}
key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3 key4 val4
$
```

**2** - Example that does not work (`key4` is equal to `*`)

```
$ PARAMS="key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=*"
$ ARRAY=(${PARAMS//[=&]/ })
$ echo ${ARRAY[@]}
key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3 key4 file.txt file2.txt file3.txt ...
$
```

The problem is that the **asterisk** (`*`) represent all files in the working directory.

Is the a way to solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @janos approach, I found the solution:

```
$ PARAMS="key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=*"
$ set -f
$ ARRAY=(${PARAMS//[=&]/ })
$ set +f
$ echo "${ARRAY[1]}"
val1
$ echo "${ARRAY[7]}"
*
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*` is expanded by the shell when it's not quoted,
both when you assign to `ARRAY` and when you `echo` it.

To make the shell not expand wildcards, you can use `set -f`.
In case of the `echo`, you can simply double-quote the value:

```
$ PARAMS="key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=*"
$ set -f  # disable wildcard expansion
$ ARRAY=(${PARAMS//[=&]/ })
$ set +f  # restore wildcard expansion
$ echo "${ARRAY[@]}"
key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3 key4 *
$ echo "${#ARRAY[@]}"
8
```

Comment: yes... but did you try to run `echo "${ARRAY[1]}"` or `echo "${ARRAY[2]}"`? I tried, but no output.

Comment: @vlauciani ah yes, I just forgot to remove the double-quotes that were left over from my previous version